# LinkedIn post scraping python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linkedin-api

I am looking for a way to scrape likes, comments and shares of a linkedIn post with python. So far I've tried with beautifulsoup but I can only obtain counts. I need the name and the info of the person who is liking, commenting or sharing. Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't tested this myself, but you can check out [linkedin-scraper library](https://pypi.org/project/linkedin-scraper/)

Comment: `Selenium` & `bs4` should do

Comment: `https://levelup.gitconnected.com/linkedin-scrapper-a3e6790099b5`

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but according to [this tutorial](https://shrikar-datakund.medium.com/scrape-comments-of-linkedin-post-in-few-lines-of-python-code-23b2d430ce69) comments can be scraped using the [bot studio library](https://linkedin-api.datakund.com/en/latest/index.html).

According to the description of the [Python3-LinkedIn library](https://pypi.org/project/python3-linkedin/) only people, companies and job listings can be searched, not comments. The same applies for the [LinkedIn Scraper library](https://pypi.org/project/linkedin-scraper/).  Happy to be corrected. It might make my research project a lot easier ;-)